# Set flag to intent dynamically from response string

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have to start an intent with some flag values which will be received from an api response.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.ANY_ACTION);
```

As shown in the above line, the value "ANY_ACTION" can be any flag value which is received as a string from api response. How can I cast the string to Intent flag?

Comment: I think you actually want extras, not flags, 'cause flags don't really make sense here. Are you just trying to pass whatever `String` you get from the server on that `Intent`? Or are you really getting values that map to `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, and such?

Comment: @MikeM., My requirement is I need to add intent.addFlags() property to my intent.  For example, intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) => in this, ".FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" this value alone I will b getting from an api as string. I need to add that as flag. Is it possible?

Comment: Oh, that is actually what you're doing, then. AFAIK, there is no method in `Intent` to map that for you. The preferable way would likely be to just create your own `Map<String, Integer>` or similar.

Comment: Can you give an exact example of the value you will get from the api? like is it "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" or just "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP"?

Comment: @MustafaDakhel, I am getting value like "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" , not the same value. It can be any intent value, but in this format.

Answer (score 1):

Before you continue on this implementation, be aware that this is not in any way a good practice, your ui state would be tightly coupled with your api, which may cause the app to be faulty in case of a wrong flag value or no flag value whatsoever.

That being said, i made this simple function to map flag strings to actual intent flags:

```
fun String.toActivityFlag() = when (this) {
    "FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND" -> Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND
    "FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION" -> Intent.FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION
    "FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES" -> Intent.FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES
    "FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES" -> Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_MATCH_EXTERNAL" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MATCH_EXTERNAL
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_RETAIN_IN_RECENTS" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RETAIN_IN_RECENTS
    "FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT" -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT
    "FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY" -> Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY
    "FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING" -> Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING
    "FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND" -> Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND
    "FLAG_RECEIVER_NO_ABORT" -> Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_NO_ABORT
    "FLAG_RECEIVER_VISIBLE_TO_INSTANT_APPS" -> Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_VISIBLE_TO_INSTANT_APPS
    else -> Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
// ... get flag from api
val flagFromApi = "ANY_FLAG"

val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
val activityFlag = flagFromApi.toActivityFlag()
intent.addFlags(activityFlag)
```